# how to click a hidden link under submenu?

Tags: python, selenium, html-lists

I failed to get a hidden link under a `<ul>`. 
`driver.find_element_by_link_text('5641B07')`, the code is OK, but if I want to find other links, failed to get them, like `'5641CM6'`
Anybody can tell me how to get the hidden link click? and how could I get all the links from the `<ul>`?

[image]

the `<ul>` structure is similar like:

```
<ul>
  <li> <a> XXX</a> </li>
  <li> <a> YYY</a> </li>
  <li> 
    <a>Add software</a>
    <ul>
      <li> <a> A </a> </li>
      <li> <a> B </a> </li>
      <li> <a> C </a> </li>
      ...........
      <li> <a> Z </a> </li>
    </ul>
   </li>

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www-01.ibm.com/products/hardware/configurator/americas/bhui/launchNI.wss")
driver.find_element_by_id("modelnumber").send_keys('8038AC1')
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("continueTop").click()
el_addSoftware=driver.find_element_by_link_text('Add software')
builder=ActionChains(driver)
builder.move_to_element(el_addSoftware).perform()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('5641CM6').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a normal dropdown.

You can use something like this

```
WebUtilities.executeScript(driver, "$('.context_menu').show()");
```

Replace '.context_menu' with your respective css selector

Click on the required option after the list is shown.

Comment: I'm not sure is it context_menu, since no keyword like it in html resource.

Comment: Try WebUtilities.executeScript(driver, "$('#yui-gen4 a').show()");